# What transportation options exist from Kodanad to Munnar?

Tags: public-transport, india, buses

In India, how do I get from Kodanad to Munnar? Is there any bus service directly from Kodanad? I tried looking up on the web however I did not find any information. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5):

You can either choose to travel by a cab (Taxi) or you can board a bus for cheaper transport.

The journey will be approx. 3 hours in a taxi, but boarding a bus may take longer time.

A cab might cost you about 2500 INR. or above for this distance.

Traveling by bus, there are few direct services from kodanad to munnar. You can either take a bus to Perumbavoor and from there another one to Munnar. Or you can go to Kothamangalam, and from there, board a bus to Munnar (Estimated cost: Below 500 INR).

Answer (score 1):

Since there aren't train stations close to Kodanad, your best bet is to drive or take a taxi. A taxi should be around $40, according to [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/s/Kodanad/Munnar).